# Expanding parameter pack as part of lambda capture in fold expression - gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, c++17

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template <int... Is>
void foo()
{
    ([i = Is]{}(), ...); 
}
```

- `clang++` (trunk) successfully compiles the code with `-std=c++17`
- `g++` (trunk) fails to compile with the following error:

  ```
  <source>: In function 'void foo()':

  <source>:4:11: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
      ([i = Is]{}(), ...);
          ^~

  <source>:4:11: note:         'Is'
  <source>:4:16: error: operand of fold expression has no unexpanded parameter packs
      ([i = Is]{}(), ...);
      ~~~~~~~~~~^~
  ```

  [on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/CKZ9mQ)

Is this a `g++` bug, or does the Standard prevent expansion of a parameter pack as part of a *lambda-introducer*?

Comment: FYI, GCC has some trouble with complex pack expansion. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491838/creating-a-variant-type-of-all-possible-map-of-key-value-types-at-compile-time/49492624#49492624)

Comment: This is [47226](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226)

Comment: @Barry: I'm done. I'll just bookmark that and make a mental note to open it before posting a question

Comment: @Barry: wait - it says that it has been fixed... yet it still happens on trunk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has the look of a bug about it.

> [**[temp.variadic]/4**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#4.12)
>
> A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the
>   instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the
>   pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends
>   on the context in which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can
>   occur in the following contexts:
>
> - ... [not relevant]
> - In a fold-expression; the pattern is the cast-expression that contains an unexpanded parameter pack.

A complete lambda expression (like you have) with a function call, is a valid [cast-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cast#nt:cast-expression) if one follows the grammar productions. There is no reason to preclude it from being a valid pattern.

Comment: Nice, do you mind linking to the paragraph on cast-expression?

Comment: @PasserBy - Don't mind at all. Made "cast-expression" a link to the start of the production.